# Do $f(x) = ax_1 + bx_2 +c, \ x_1 \in R, x_2 \in R$ and $g(v) = wv + b, \ v \in R^2$ have the same domain?

Tags: functions

per [mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Domain.html)

> The term `domain` is most commonly used to describe the set of values
>   for which a function (map, transformation, etc.) is defined. For
>   example, a function f(x) that is defined for real values $x \in R$ has
>   domain $\mathbb R$, and is sometimes said to be "a function over the reals."

Here are 2 functions.

$f(x) = ax_1 + bx_2 +c, \quad where \quad x_1 \in R, x_2 \in R, \quad \text{a, b, c are constants}$

$g(v) = wv + b, \quad where \quad v \in R^2, \quad \text{w, b are constants}$

Do they have the same domain, that is $R^2$?

I guess so, and I need a double check.

Comment: I think the answer given below emphasizes a good point, which is that functions require 3 pieces of information: $f:A \to B$, so the rule is $f$, the domain is $A$ and the target space is $B$. So, logically speaking, you SHOULD NOT give the formula, like $f(x) = ax_1 + b_2 + c$ first. The first thing you need to do is specify the domain and target space. It is only after you specify them that you should write down the "rule". Hence, you should say something like: let $a,b,c \in \Bbb{R}$ be given constants and define $f: \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}$ by $f(x_1,x_2) = ax_1 + bx_2 + c$

Comment: When you phrase things in this manner, it is clear that the domain is $\Bbb{R}^2$. (by the way the definition for $g$ makes no sense because $wv$ is a vector while $b$ is just a number, so the RHS of $g(v) = \dots$ doesn't make sense). So, the answer to a question like "do they have the same domain $\Bbb{R}^2$" is a simple "yes/no", and the justification is "by definition". That's it; it doesn't make sense to give a formula for $f(x)$ and $g(v)$ and then ask if they have the same domain. YOU need to specify what the domain and target space are BEFORE you write down a formula.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Your comments is very helpful. Would you please take a look at this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3312863/678038) and whether it is in the right form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did NOT give two functions.

A function normaly consists of three things, where the domain and range are a part of it.

So a function is given by $f:D\to R$ with $x\mapsto f(x)$.

You just give:

$f(x)=ax_1+bx_2+c$. So you miss the first part, which is important.

What is odd here, is that there is no $x$ on the RHS of the functional equation. So I guess $(x_1,x_2)=x\in\mathbb{R}^2$ is meant.

Also this:

> For example, a function $f(x)$ that is defined for real values x∈R has domain R, and is sometimes said to be "a function over the reals."

from your quote names the function $f(x)$, but the 'name' of that function is $f$.
$f(x)$ is a value in the range of $f$, which is a common mistake.

So do your 'functions' have the same domain?
They could. Nothing would stop you of defining them with $\mathbb{R}^2$ as domain.

But you could also define unique domains for each function. 
You can be really flexible here. What is for sure is just, that $D\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ in both cases for $f$ and $g$ to make sense.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What does "LHS" in "the LHS of the functional equation" mean?

Comment: @yaojp LHS and RHS is the short term for 'lefthand side' and 'right hand side'. You these these terms constantly on this website. People get lazy from time to time. :) Also with LHS for example, is meant the left side of the equation $\text{LHS}~=~\text{RHS}$

Comment: Also I meant RHS... I edit that...

Comment: Would you please take a look at this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3312863/678038) and whether it is in the right form?

Comment: @yaojp I already looked at it and would like to help, but I do not know anything about statistics and what the conventions are in that field. Please consider asking Mohammed Riazi-Kermani for clearification if something is unclear. Besides that it looks fine. You just want to use brackets: $(x_1,x_2)\mapsto \dotso$