# Is this $f:R^2\to R$ with $x_1, x_2\mapsto \beta _{0} + \beta_{1}x_{1} + \beta_{2}x_{2}$ the right form of the definition of a function?

Tags: functions, machine-learning

Per [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression)

> In statistics, [linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) is a linear approach to modeling
>   the relationship between a scalar response (or dependent variable) and
>   one or more explanatory variables (or independent variables).
>
> the model takes the form
>
> ${\displaystyle y_{i}=\beta _{0}+\beta _{1}x_{i1}+\cdots +\beta
> > _{p}x_{ip}+\varepsilon _{i}=\mathbf {x} _{i}^{\mathsf {T}}{\boldsymbol {\beta }}+\varepsilon _{i},\qquad i=1,\ldots ,n,}$
>
> where T denotes the transpose, so that $x_i^Tβ$ is the inner product
>   between vectors $x_i$ and β.

simplified,

$y_1 = \beta _{0} + \beta_{1}x_{1} + \beta_{2}x_{2} \tag{1}$

I guess equation 1 could be represented as a function, things like

$f:R^2\to R$ with $x_1, x_2\mapsto \beta _{0} + \beta_{1}x_{1} + \beta_{2}x_{2}$

So, is above the right form of the definition of a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ordered pairs is normal for such functions. You may write $$f(x_1,x_2)=\alpha_0 +\alpha_1x_1+\alpha_2x_2$$ or $$f:(x_1,x_2)\to \alpha_0+\alpha_1x_1+\alpha_1x_2$$